# pivot_longer: change structure of dataframe for barplot

Tags: pivot

I have this dataframe

```
    Treatment   easy   medium   hard
1   Happiness   4.02    2.86    3.54
2   Neutral     4.26    3.04    3.40
3   Sadness     3.78    3.14    1.92
```

and I want to change it into this one, because I need to create a barplot:

```
   Treatment  task     value
1  Happiness  easy     4.02
2  Happiness  medium   2.86
3  Happiness  hard     3.54
4  Neutral    easy     4.26
5  Neutral    medium   3.04
6  Neutral    hard     3.40
7  Sadness    easy     3.78
8  Sadness    medium   3.14
9  Sadness    hard     1.92
```

How can I change it using `tidyr::pivot_longer`? I don't know how to define the parameters of this command.

Thank you very much for your help!!!

Answer (score 0):

Here is the code:

```
tab_ris1=pivot_longer(tab_ris,cols=c("easy","medium","hard"),names_to="task",values_to="value")
tab_ris1
```